# Is this the most I can get from Python multiprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have data, which is in a text file. Each line is a computation to do. This file has around 100 000 000 lines.

First I load everything into the ram, then I have a a method that performs the computation and gives the following results:

```
def process(data_line):
    #do computation
    return result
```

Then I call it like this with packets of 2000 lines and then save the result to disk :

```
POOL_SIZE = 15 #nbcore - 1
PACKET_SIZE = 2000
pool = Pool(processes=POOL_SIZE)

data_lines = util.load_data_lines(to_be_computed_filename)
number_of_packets = int(number_of_lines/ PACKET_SIZE)
for i in range(number_of_packets):
    lines_packet = data_lines[:PACKET_SIZE]
    data_lines = data_lines[PACKET_SIZE:]
    results = pool.map(process, lines_packet)
    save_computed_data_to_disk(to_be_computed_filename, results)

# process the last packet, which is smaller
results.extend(pool.map(process, data_lines))
save_computed_data_to_disk(to_be_computed_filename, results)
print("Done")
```

The problem is, while I was writing to disk, my CPU is computing nothing and has 8 cores. It is looking at the task manager and it seems that quite a lot of CPU time is lost.

I have to write to disk after having completed my computation because the results are 1000 times larger than the input.
Anyways, I would have to write to the disk at some point. If time is not lost here, it will be lost later.

[image: CPUTime]

What could I do to allow one core to write to disk, while still computing with the others? Switch to C?

At this rate I can process 100 millions lines in 75h, but I have 12 billions lines to process, so any improvement is welcome.

example of timings:

```
Processing packet 2/15 953 of C:/processing/drop_zone\to_be_processed_txt_files\t_to_compute_303620.txt
Launching task and waiting for it to finish...
Task completed, Continuing
Packet was processed in 11.534576654434204 seconds
We are currently going at a rate of 0.002306915330886841 sec/words
Which is 433.47928145051293 words per seconds
Saving in temporary file
Printing writing 5000 computed line to disk took 0.04400920867919922 seconds
saving word to resume from : 06 20 25 00 00
Estimated time for processing the remaining packets is : 51:19:25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have 8 cores, yet you have:

```
POOL_SIZE = 15 #nbcore - 1
```

Assuming you want to leave one processor free (presumably for the main process?) why wouldn't this number be 7? But why do you even want to read a processor free? You are making successive calls to `map`. While the main process is waiting for these calls to return, it requires know CPU. This is why if you do not specify a pool size when you instantiate your pool it defaults to the number of CPUs you have and not that number minus one. I will have more to say about this below.

Since you have a very large, in-memory list, is it possible that you are expending waisted cycles in your loop rewriting this list on each iteration of the loop. Instead, you can just take a slice of the list and pass that as the iterable argument to `map`:

```
POOL_SIZE = 15 # ????
PACKET_SIZE = 2000
data_lines = util.load_data_lines(to_be_computed_filename)
number_of_packets, remainder = divmod(number_of_lines, PACKET_SIZE)
with Pool(processes=POOL_SIZE) as pool:
    offset = 0
    for i in range(number_of_packets):
        results = pool.map(process, data_lines[offset:offset+PACKET_SIZE])
        offset += PACKET_SIZE
        save_computed_data_to_disk(to_be_computed_filename, results)
    if remainder:
        results = pool.map(process, data_lines[offset:offset+remainder])
        save_computed_data_to_disk(to_be_computed_filename, results)
print("Done")
```

Between each call to `map` the main process is writing out the results to `to_be_computed_filename`. In the meanwhile, **every process in your pool is sitting idle.** This should be given to another process (actually a thread running under the main process):

```
import multiprocessing
import queue
import threading

POOL_SIZE = 15 # ????
PACKET_SIZE = 2000
data_lines = util.load_data_lines(to_be_computed_filename)
number_of_packets, remainder = divmod(number_of_lines, PACKET_SIZE)

def save_data(q):
    while True:
        results = q.get()
        if results is None:
            return # signal to terminate
        save_computed_data_to_disk(to_be_computed_filename, results)

q = queue.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target=save_data, args=(q,))
t.start()

with Pool(processes=POOL_SIZE) as pool:
    offset = 0
    for i in range(number_of_packets):
        results = pool.map(process, data_lines[offset:offset+PACKET_SIZE])
        offset += PACKET_SIZE
        q.put(results)
    if remainder:
        results = pool.map(process, data_lines[offset:offset+remainder])
        q.put(results)
q.put(None)
t.join() # wait for thread to terminate
print("Done")
```

I've chosen to run `save_data` in a thread of the main process. This could also be another process in which case you would need to use a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance. But I figured the main process thread is mostly waiting for the `map` to complete and there would not be competition for the GIL. Now if you do not leave a processor free for the threading job, `save_data`, it may end up doing most of the saving only after all of the results have been created. You would need to experiment a bit with this.

Ideally, I would also modify the reading of the input file so as to not have to first read it all into memory but rather read it line by line yielding 2000 line chunks and submitting those as jobs for `map` to process:

```
import multiprocessing
import queue
import threading

POOL_SIZE = 15 # ????
PACKET_SIZE = 2000


def save_data(q):
    while True:
        results = q.get()
        if results is None:
            return # signal to terminate
        save_computed_data_to_disk(to_be_computed_filename, results)


def read_data():
    """
    yield lists of PACKET_SIZE
    """
    lines = []
    with open(some_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in iter(f.readline(), ''):
            lines.append(line)
            if len(lines) == PACKET_SIZE:
                yield lines
                lines = []
        if lines:
            yield lines

q = queue.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target=save_data, args=(q,))
t.start()

with Pool(processes=POOL_SIZE) as pool:
    for l in read_data():
        results = pool.map(process, l)
        q.put(results)
q.put(None)
t.join() # wait for thread to terminate
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note: This SharedMemory works only for Python >= 3.8 since it first appeared there**

Start 3 kinds of processes: Reader, Processor(s), Writer.

Have Reader process read the file incrementally, sharing the result via `shared_memory` and Queue.

Have the Processor(s) consume the Queue, consume the shared_memory, and return the result(s) via another Queue. Again, as shared_memory.

Have the Writer process consume the second Queue, writing to the destination file.

Have them all communicate through, say, some `Event`s or `DictProxy`, with the MainProcess who will act as the orchestrator.

---

#### Example:

```py
import time
import random
import hashlib
import multiprocessing as MP

from queue import Queue, Empty

# noinspection PyCompatibility
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

from typing import Dict, List


def readerfunc(
        shm_arr: List[SharedMemory], q_out: Queue, procr_ready: Dict[str, bool]
):
    numshm = len(shm_arr)
    for batch in range(1, 6):
        print(f"Reading batch #{batch}")
        for shm in shm_arr:
            #### Simulated Reading ####
            for j in range(0, shm.size):
                shm.buf[j] = random.randint(0, 255)
            #### ####
            q_out.put((batch, shm))
        # Need to sync here because we're reusing the same SharedMemory,
        # so gotta wait until all processors are done before sending the
        # next batch
        while not q_out.empty() or not all(procr_ready.values()):
            time.sleep(1.0)


def processorfunc(
        q_in: Queue, q_out: Queue, suicide: type(MP.Event()), procr_ready: Dict[str, bool]
):
    pname = MP.current_process().name
    procr_ready[pname] = False
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        procr_ready[pname] = True
        if q_in.empty() and suicide.is_set():
            break
        try:
            batch, shm = q_in.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            continue
        print(pname, "got batch", batch)
        procr_ready[pname] = False
        #### Simulated Processing ####
        h = hashlib.blake2b(shm.buf, digest_size=4, person=b"processor")
        time.sleep(random.uniform(5.0, 7.0))
        #### ####
        q_out.put((pname, h.hexdigest()))


def writerfunc(q_in: Queue, suicide: type(MP.Event())):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        if q_in.empty() and suicide.is_set():
            break
        try:
            pname, digest = q_in.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            continue
        print("Writing", pname, digest)
        #### Simulated Writing ####
        time.sleep(random.uniform(3.0, 6.0))
        #### ####
        print("Writing", pname, digest, "done")


def main():
    shm_arr = [
        SharedMemory(create=True, size=1024)
        for _ in range(0, 5)
    ]
    q_read = MP.Queue()
    q_write = MP.Queue()
    procr_ready = MP.Manager().dict()
    poison = MP.Event()
    poison.clear()

    reader = MP.Process(target=readerfunc, args=(shm_arr, q_read, procr_ready))

    procrs = []
    for n in range(0, 3):
        p = MP.Process(
            target=processorfunc, name=f"Proc{n}", args=(q_read, q_write, poison, procr_ready)
        )
        procrs.append(p)

    writer = MP.Process(target=writerfunc, args=(q_write, poison))

    reader.start()
    [p.start() for p in procrs]
    writer.start()

    reader.join()
    print("Reader has ended")

    while not all(procr_ready.values()):
        time.sleep(5.0)
    poison.set()
    [p.join() for p in procrs]
    print("Processors have ended")

    writer.join()
    print("Writer has ended")

    [shm.close() for shm in shm_arr]
    [shm.unlink() for shm in shm_arr]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind for the code is to run the saving function in the thread. By this we exclude the bottelneck of waiting disk writing. Like so:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
future = executor.submit(save_computed_data_to_disk, to_be_computed_filename, results)
saving_futures.append(future)
...
concurrent.futures.wait(saving_futures, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)  # wait all saved to disk after processing
print("Done")
```

Comment: The OP needs to spread the effort across mulriple CPUs simultaneous, so Threading wont work.

Comment: Why several threads that consume almost no CPU, but only write to disk, won't work?

Comment: They will - the normal 'effiicent model' for Python threading is 1 Producer, and more than one I/O heavy consumer threads. But from what I understand the OP has some CPU heavy processing to do on each file so that needs multiple CPU heavy threads; which is where Python multi-threading has a major issue. Other languages can put threads across murliple CPUs - but Python can't.

Comment: The OP has a *multiprocessing* pool invocation (map) for CPU bound tasks on every iterations, but between iterations he saves a processing result to file and wait for this, I suggest do not wait it and go straight to the next iteration, saving to the file in the background threads. For the disk writing no need to leverage multiple CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

I made two assumptions: The writing is hitting the I/O bound, not the CPU bound - meaning that throwing more cores onto writing would not improve the performance. And the `process` function contains some heavy computations.

I would approach it differently:

1. Split up the large list into a list of list
2. Feed it than into the processes
3. Store the total result

Here is the example code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

data_lines = [0]*10000 # read it from file
size = 2000

# Split the list into a list of list (with chunksize `size`)
work = [data_lines[i:i + size] for i in range(0, len(data_lines), size)]

def process(data):
    result = len(data) # some something fancy
    return result

with mp.Pool() as p:
    result = p.map(process, work)

save_computed_data_to_disk(file_name, result)
```

On meta: You may also have a look into [`numpy`](https://numpy.org) or [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org) (depending on the data) because it sounds that you would like to do something into that direction.

Comment: the result variable would be something like 80GB far too high for my computer.

plus it would just displace the "writing to disk with 7 core idle" to the end of the program, I would like to write at the same time that I'm computing to not waste any CPU cycles.

Comment: Well, as I said writing to disk is I/O bounded (storing data from RAM to HDD or SSD), so I don't think there is any benefit of using multiple cores.

Comment: Well if you write like this : compute with 16 core, write with 1 core while computing with the 15 other cores, then switch back to computing with 16 core, and do this forever,

it will be faster than computing with 16 core then writing with 1 core.